# <div> of dropdown-menu does not get visible in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a dropdown-menu, which you can look at at this link: [Dropdownmenu](http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/localfilter_austria.php)

It works fine in Firefox and Edge, but the subcategories won´t get visible in Chrome.

Here's the php code:

```
$country = array(
    "Vorarlberg" => array('Bludenz', 'Feldkirch', 'Dornbirn', 'Bregenz'),

    "Tirol" => array('Imst', 'Innsbruck-Stadt', 'Innsbruck-Land', 'Kitzbühel', 'Kufstein', 'Landeck', 'Reutte', 'Schwaz'),

    "Salzburg" => array('Salzburg-Stadt', 'Hallein', 'Salzburg-Umgebung', 'St. Johann im Pongau', 'Tamsweg', 'Zell am See'),    
);

foreach ($country as $key => $value) {

    echo '<div class="countryselect" data-countryselect="'.$key.'">';
    echo $key;

    echo '<div class="districtselectwrap" data-countrydistrictopen="'.$key.'">';

    foreach ($value as $district){

        echo '<div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="'.$district.'">';
        echo $district;
        echo '</div>';  
    }

    echo '</div>';  
    echo '</div>';

}

echo '<div class="countryselect glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" data-countryselect="reset" style="margin-top: -1px;"></div>';
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(".countryselect").on('click', function(){

    $('.districtselectwrap').css('display', 'none');

    var country = $(this).data('countryselect');

    $('.districtselectwrap[data-countrydistrictopen="'+country+'"]').css('display', 'block', 'important');

});
```

And those are the styles:

```
.countryselect {
    position: relative;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    display: inline-table;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background-color: #555;
}
.districtselectwrap {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 44px;
}
.districtselect {
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #555;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I open the Dev-Tools from Chrome, I can see that the style gets switched from display "none" to "block". The `<div>`'s get "rendered" as well, but are not visible. My ad blocker is deactivated. Has anyone an idea what the problem could be? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the position to relative on `.districtselectwrap` changes the width of the parent element once the sub menu is open.

What I'm seeing is that in Chrome, `overflow: hidden;` on `.countryselect` is hiding the `<div>`.

Why it's not hiding it in FF and Edge I'm not sure exactly I'd have to do a little Googling but I believe it has to do with how overflow works on block elements vs. table elements.

On your `.countryselect` element try removing `overflow: hidden` and change display to `inline-block`:

```
.countryselect {
    position: relative;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float: left;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

With that it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change absolute to relative

```
.districtselectwrap {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Used `relative` instead of `absolute` ,also add `$('.districtselectwrap').css('display', 'none');` to prevent default opening of your sub menu . Working example :

```js
//add this line to prevent default opening of option
 $('.districtselectwrap').css('display', 'none');
 
  $(".countryselect").on('click', function() {

      $('.districtselectwrap').css('display', 'none');

      var country = $(this).data('countryselect');

      $('.districtselectwrap[data-countrydistrictopen="' + country + '"]').css('display', 'block', 'important');

    });
```

```css
.countryselect {
    position: relative;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    display: inline-table;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background-color: #555;
}
.districtselectwrap {
    position:relative; /*change this*/
    display: none;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 44px;
}
.districtselect {
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #555;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="countryselect" data-countryselect="Vorarlberg">Vorarlberg
    <div class="districtselectwrap" data-countrydistrictopen="Vorarlberg" style="display: none;">
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Bludenz">Bludenz</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Feldkirch">Feldkirch</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Dornbirn">Dornbirn</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Bregenz">Bregenz</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="countryselect" data-countryselect="Tirol">Tirol
    <div class="districtselectwrap" data-countrydistrictopen="Tirol" style="display: none;">
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Imst">Imst</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Innsbruck-Stadt">Innsbruck-Stadt</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Innsbruck-Land">Innsbruck-Land</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Kitzbühel">Kitzbühel</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Kufstein">Kufstein</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Landeck">Landeck</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Reutte">Reutte</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Schwaz">Schwaz</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="countryselect" data-countryselect="Salzburg">Salzburg
    <div class="districtselectwrap" data-countrydistrictopen="Salzburg" style="display: block;">
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Salzburg-Stadt">Salzburg-Stadt</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Hallein">Hallein</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Salzburg-Umgebung">Salzburg-Umgebung</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="St. Johann im Pongau">St. Johann im Pongau</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Tamsweg">Tamsweg</div>
      <div class="districtselect" data-districtselect="Zell am See">Zell am See</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="countryselect glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" data-countryselect="reset" style="margin-top: -1px;"></div>

 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with CSS Style Sheet. Please change the css for districtselectwrap to the following:

```
.districtselectwrap {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 44px;
}
```

This will do the trick and work fine then.

I hope this helps